# Is there any relation between temperature dependence of resistance and fermi energy in metals?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, electrical-resistance, metals

Given that the resistance varies linearly with temperature in metals, is there any way we can calculate the Fermi energy from this information?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the conductivity $\sigma=\frac{1}{\rho}$ of a metal scales like $\propto\frac{1}{T}$ is due to *elastic electron-phonon scattering*, i.e. the coulombian interaction between the charge density fluctuation induce by a [phonon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) and an electron.

In an incoherent transport theory of electron in solids (i.e. avoiding corrections due to interferences like [weak localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_localization)), the conductivity is well described by the [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) :
$$
\sigma=\frac{ne^2\tau}{m}
$$
where $\tau$ is the typical time scale for the electron to "collide" and change its momentum, $n$ is the electron density. There are various processes that determine $\tau$, one is elastic electron-phonon scattering, but there is inelastic electron-phonon scattering, electron-electron scattering and scattering on static impurities too, etc. All of these processes have different scaling in respect of the temperature $T$.

It turns out that at hight temperature (room temperature), elastic electron-phonon scattering is the dominant one. It can be shown that :
$$
\tau_{\text{el-ph}}=\frac{\hbar}{k_B T}
$$
which does not depend on the Fermi energy. However, the Fermi momentum $k_F$ and the electron density $n$ are bound to each other by :
$$
k_F^3=3\pi^2n\quad\text{i.e.}\quad n=\frac{1}{3\pi^2}\left(\frac{2mE_F}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}
$$
Then the room temperature resistivity reads :
$$
\rho=\frac{3\pi^2m\,k_BT}{\hbar e^2}\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2mE_F}\right)^{3/2}\propto T
$$

Comment: Can you give a reference for $\tau_{\text{el-ph}}=\hbar/(k_BT)$?

Answer (score -1):

In my point of view, it is independent thing.
Dependence of resistance on temperature is determined by Nernst-Einstein equation.
$$
R=\frac{l k_B T}{S D Z^2 e^2 C}
$$
where $T$ -is a temperature of resistance, $k_B$ is a Boltzmann constant, l- length, S - cross sectional area, $D$ - diffusion coefficient, $C$ is a charge carrier density, $Z$ is a amount of electric charge carrier, and $e$ is a electron charge.
This equation is followed from kinetic theory. 
In point of view Fermi energy is required than there is not band gap(it means that it is metal).

Comment: Your argument cannot hold since the number $n$ of electrons per unit volume ($C$ in your equation) is given by the Fermi energy : $$
E_F=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}(3\pi^2 n)^{2/3}
$$